# Inserting values using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to insert a value in the middle of a string using regex. String looks like this (there is more text before and after that I need, but that is irrelevant for sample purposes - I think):

```
test $1 xyz
```

I search for a value of (.*), and have $1 set to insert the value from another column.

The output looks like this:
    test ADS xyztest xyz

How can I set this up to return: test ADS xyz

Comment: Maybe `test (.*?) xyz`?

Comment: What is the logic to decide you want to return that? And what is your input data in the example case?

Comment: Is `test` and `xyz` constant? Can you more clearly define the patterns for which you're searching?

Comment: I think your question would benefit from additional samples of inputs and expected outputs. We shouldn't have to guess what you're trying to accomplish. If your samples are sufficient, something like `test (.+) xyz` should work. I presume that's not what you're after...

Comment: Are you looking for values within text that are prepended with a `$`? The most important thing about constructing regexes is to understand your inputs. This can greatly affect the construction of your regex (i.e. it can be specific or vague) usually MVP is the way to go with regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `(.*\w)` for the regex which should return the whole word you want to insert into your string.

For the final string output you'll then use: `test $1 xyz`